# Make a 3D model from z stack of 2D images in python

Tags: 3d, surface, triangulation

I am working with human cells and have a "z stack" (a set of 2d images taken at regular intervals in z with a light microscope) such that I can see all the cells.

[zstack][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul1TA.jpg)

I am wondering how could I make a 3D model in python so that I would be able to count of the cells?

I read that maybe I could use delunay triangulation, but havent seen that done on real images. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can try this ImageJ function : https://imagej.net/Z-functions

ImageJ is an open source free software, meaning that if it works and you like the result, you can find the source code (in java) of the function and adapt/translate it to integrate it to your software. I have done it a few times already with different functions.

Comment: I have tried imagej. When I try to render it in 3D i just get weird results. I am guessing that I need to input pixel widht height and dept in order to make a 3d model? If so, how do I determine that? What about the distance between stacks?

Answer (score 0):

You need [marching cubes](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) algorithm. I don't know if a ready to use Python implementation exists.